# Flash Builder for iOS projects

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, flash-builder

How does Flash Builder work for iOS projects? Does it give me a generated xcode project file? Or do I have to submit the flash builder project to the App Store? Also,
is it worth the hype (cross platform) or are the apps buggy and laggy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, it uses LLVM to create binaries/app-bundles you can upload directly.  Never seen an app, so can't answer about what it looks like.